# Design Pattern to adding new capability to my class

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles

I'm trying to find a solution for my structure. Let me try to tell what I am doing.

I have two class "Englishman" and "CanadaMan" and some capability classes "CanSpeakEnglish", "CanSpeakFrench"

```
class CanTalkEnglish{
    Database database;
    void TalkEnglish(){
      Console.Write(" am taking {this.database.MyLanguage}");
    } 
};

class CanTalkFrench{
    Database database;
    void TalkFrench(){
      Console.Write("Je parle {this.database.MyLanguage}");
    }
};

class Englishman : public CanTalkEnglish {
    Database database;
    void Talk(){
       if (this->database.Mood == "OpenToCommunication"){
         this->TalkEnglish();
       }
   }
};

class CanadaMan : public CanTalkEnglish,CanTalkFrench {
    Database database;
    void Talk(){
       if (this->database.Mood == "OpenToCommunication"){
         this->TalkEnglish();
         this->TalkFrench();
       }
   }
};
```

This is the structure that I imagine, but the problem is the "database". All "Person" classes and all "Capability" classes will need it. But this.database call is ambiguous, is there a design pattern to manage this kind of requirement?

Comment: I assume that the code you show is pseudo-code? Because if it's not then you need to [edit] your question to make sure that the tags matches the code.

Comment: You can just provide fully qualified name for your `database` object to avoid ambiguity

Comment: As for your problem, in this case perhaps a singleton might be useful for the `database` object?

Comment: Why do you think inheritance is a good design to use here?  At least try to avoid diamond inheritance.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Even better would be to inject an interface (abstract baseclass) to the classes. Singletons/globals make unit testing way too hard.

Comment: i tried to fix some issues in your code. I assume you want public inheritance. If private inheritance was on purpose please correct

Comment: I also assume the methods should all be `const`, however, its your code,please review

Comment: Questionable design aside, you should use `virtual inheritance` to make sure that each class instance only have a single unique database.

Comment: your immediate issue of ambiguous name is resolved by fully qualifying the name, eg `CanTalkFrench::database` instead of just `database`. However, that doesnt fix your design

Comment: The design seems to broken if you need to know that CanTalkEnglish provide a method TalkEnglish and the CanTalkFrench class needs to provide TalkFrench. This violates the idea of information hiding and makes the inheritance design useless.

Comment: @Mestkon: Your idea of virtual inheritance looks fine to have a single base of database containing class but Pepijn exactly votes to don't do it :-) For me is quite unclear what the class structure should solve...

Comment: @Klaus That's why I ignored the design aspect and only responded to the actual error. Everyone else has already commented about the questionable design.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Your comments and answers usually seem *very* reasonable and knowledgeable, yet you encourage the use of a *singleton* here?? A glorified global variable, with all the tight coupling/construction & destruction order problems/readability mess/etc that global variables come with.. I'm genuinely surprised.

Comment: for design you need to consider the Why? and What for? not just one issue of a single member. Why did you write those classes in the first place. Why is there inheritance? What do you need polymorphism for?

Comment: @OP So an `Englishman` is-a `CanTalkEnglish`?  Does that sound right to you?  That is what your design is stating.  The same with `CanadaMan` -- a man *is-a* language?  It's like saying a `Car` is a `Sparkplug`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to structure your interfaces better:

```
struct Database {};

struct EnglishSpeaking {
    virtual void speakEnglish() = 0;
    virtual ~EnglishSpeaking() = default;
};

struct FrenchSpeaking {
    virtual void speakFrench() = 0;
    virtual ~FrenchSpeaking() = default;
};

struct Stateful {
    Database database;
    virtual ~Stateful() = default;
};

struct EnglishMan : EnglishSpeaking, Stateful {
    void speakEnglish() override;
};

struct AustralianMan : EnglishSpeaking, Stateful {
    void speakEnglish() override;
};

struct CanadianMan : EnglishSpeaking, FrenchSpeaking, Stateful {
    void speakEnglish() override;
    void speakFrench() override;
};
```

Note that some people will find the claim that no Englishman speaks french or that all Canadian men speak french outrageous.

Comment: @fobus It's not about racism, it's about pointing out that this class structure is not flexible enough for a real-life use case.